# Autoplay for slides in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/th6cfw7o/).

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({   
    anchors: ['home', 'about', 'contact'],
    afterRender: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

By default slides move from left to right. My problem: when we come to last slide - animate of slides is happening from right to left, through other slides. How can i implement animate slides from last slide to first by default animate (from left to right)?

For vertical scrolling it have already done. If we write `continuousVertical: true` will get [this rusult](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/continuous.html).

Comment: This is possible with the fullpage.js extension Scroll Horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue on the fullPage github project which I think is talking about what you're trying to do: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/124

The plugin author says he will not include the feature but later says you can contact him for help customising the plugin.

There is also a comment from someone with a workaround you could try:

> 1. when scroll to the last slide, start a setTimeout() for the display time, then "fade out" all slides.
> 2. when scroll to the first slide, start a setTimeout() for the "pull back" action, then "fade in" all slides.