# Automatically playing or scrolling slides in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have read the many posts about wanting an automatic slider. I have seen the code. I have copied and pasted the code. And yet, the slides just sit there. They can be advanced manually with the arrows, but I cannot get them to advance automatically.

For clarification, I am not talking about sections, I am talking about slides. What I want is for section1 to have three or four slides that scroll automatically, just like many 3rd party sliders do. Then I want section2 and section3 to be regular pages without slides.

I have tried integrating a third party slider into fullpage, but when the slider advances to the next slide, it also triggers fullpage to advance to the next section as well. There must be some duplicate code that causes this.  I have tried three different sliders and they all have this behavior.  Also, I'd rather not use a third party slider anyway.

BTW, the template I am starting with is 'active-slide.html'

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3'],
        loopBottom: true,

        afterRender: function () {
          setInterval(function () {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
          }, 2500);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoplay for slides in fullpage.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296112/autoplay-for-slides-in-fullpage-js)

Comment: What about the old answers didn't answer your question?

Comment: When the code was plugged in, the slides didn't move.  Anytime I try to ask about it, I am just told that the question has already been asked.   It's like everyone is sick of hearing about it and just gives a boilerplate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your whole code is right, you just have to change one line in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3'],
        loopBottom: true,
        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Change `$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();`
to `fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question!

Answer (score 0):

As I replied [time ago on the github forurm](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/532#issuecomment-47360515):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3'],
        loopBottom: true,
        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

However, I would encourage you to use fullPage.js 3 api if you do not want to use jQuery:

Here's the full example as detailed on [fullPage help](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/help/how-to-autoplay-horizontal-slides-in-fullpage-js/):

```
var g_interval;
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'YOUR KEY HERE',
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],  
  afterLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
    clearInterval(g_interval);
    
    // 1000 milliseconds lapse
    const lapse = 1000;
    
    if(destination.item.querySelectorAll('.fp-slides').length){
      g_interval = setInterval(function () {
        fullpage_api.moveSlideRight();
      }, lapse);
    }
  }
});
```